# WPF DataGrid DataBinding From Different Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Please see the code below. I am trying to display two different list in the same `datagrid`. In my `FormulaUploadViewModel` I have 2 different list that I need to implement into the `datagrid`. The `DataGridTextColumn` in the `datagrid` will fetch the values from `SelectedData` list and `comboBox` will fetch the values from `PersonList`. I set the `DataContext="{DynamicResource FormulaUploadViewModel}`. Thank you.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SSM.Formulas.FormulaUploadView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SSM.Formulas"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         MinWidth="800"
         d:DataContext="{DynamicResource FormulaUploadViewModel}">

    <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding PersonId, Delay=500, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="4">

    <DataGrid x:Name="selectGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedData}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" MinHeight="700">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Flow Value" Binding="{Binding point}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dev-Code" Binding="{Binding code}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Solvent">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" DisplayMemberPath="PersonCode" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding PersonCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>       
</Grid>
```

```
public class FormulaUploadViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public FormulaUploadViewModel()
    {
        SelectedData = new List<Data>();
        PersonList = new List<PersonList>();
        PersonId=100;
    }
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also, I am trying to show combo's selecteditem from SelectedData and itemsource from PersonList.

Comment: Pls state clearly what seems to be wrong with your code! you are not getting what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that ItemsSource of anything (column, column's datatemplate etc.) inside DataGrid must be something relevant to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid itself. To make it clearer, your "PersonList" has to be a property inside your "SelectedData" object.

You can't (or at least I tried and haven't succeeded) have two different DataContexts, 1 for the DataGrid and 1 for the column inside it.

So, here's my sample code for you:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        ObservableCollection<Person> pList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        pList.Add(new Person { Name = "Ma", ID = "1" });
        pList.Add(new Person { Name = "ta", ID = "2" });
        pList.Add(new Person { Name = "ha", ID = "3" });
        pList.Add(new Person { Name = "ri", ID = "4" });

        DataList = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        DataList.Add(new Data { Point = "point1", Code = "code1", PersonList = pList });
        DataList.Add(new Data { Point = "point2", Code = "code2", PersonList = pList });
        DataList.Add(new Data { Point = "point3", Code = "code3", PersonList = pList });
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }
    public string Point { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Flow Value" Binding="{Binding Point}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dev-Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Solvent">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: That's what it looks like]